# Need to launch a "command line runner" spring boot app in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, command-line, spring-boot-2

I need to adapt my existing spring boot app to AWS Lambda.

- I have a Spring Boot App that is use as an application installer, it initialize Database, copy files and other stuff that we will skip for Lambda use and stopped with a System.exit(0) when all the steps passed.
- For modularity, we use CommandLineRunner as Bean and conditional properties to do or not an step.
- For now application is launched in command line with custom application.yml and with a "mode" as argument (INSTALL, UNINSTALL, DATABASE_INSTALL).
- What do you think is the recommended way to adapt my application to be launch in a Lambda ? It will be a one time launch.

In the majority of example we can find in internet they use  SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler but I'm not sure it is the way I need to implement my Handler.

Thanks for your suggestions.

I've try to check examples but all treats about APIs and WS based.